# RegEx to extract Date from time

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

I have the following date & time and looking to convert it to a simple digit using RegEx

What I have: 2017-11-02T04:00:00Z

What I want to convert it to: 20171102 (including leading zeros of months/dates)

Is this possible with RegEx? Was able to only get '2017-' after hours of work using '^(.*?)-'

Seems harder and harder, any helping hand is much appreciated

Edit: Showing where I am trying this. I am trying to do this on Nintex for SharePoint. But prior to that, I am using www.regEx101.com to validate

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a date library?

Comment: Why not using a date/time parsing module instead?

Comment: Where are you trying the regex? Show the code.

Comment: Added the place I am trying to use RegEx

Comment: just replace `-` with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex with the *Replace* template:

```
^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*
```

and provide

```
$1$2$3
```

as the replacement pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1 (later referenced to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern): four digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1 (later referenced to with `$2` backreference from the replacement pattern): two digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d{2})` - Group 3 (later referenced to with `$3` backreference from the replacement pattern): two digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Cd%7B4%7D%29-%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29-%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29.*&i=2017-11-02T04%3A00%3A00Z&r=%241%242%243).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`?

This will match exactly four digits, followed by a hyphen, followed by 2 digits, followed by another hyphen, followed by another 2 digits.

```js
var str = "2017-11-02T04:00:00Z";
var res = str.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It works on regex101. But on Ninex the answer seems to be 'T04:00:00Z'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude characters from a match group in regex, so you have to use three match groups. I use command line sed to experiment with regex. Here is some output to show what I mean:

```
$ echo '2017-11-02T04:00:00Z'|sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)T.*$/\1\2\3/'
20171102
```

This command matches each sequence of an arbitrary length of numbers within a separate capture group, and then replaces the entire string with the three groups. How your language implements this functionality will vary.